# How do I render Error 404 page in a static client side rendered page in Next js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, http-status-code-404

```
import { onAuthStateChanged } from "firebase/auth";
import Link from "next/link";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { auth } from "../../lib/firebase";

export default function Username() {
  const [context, setContext] = useState();
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const router = useRouter();
  useEffect(() => {
    onAuthStateChanged(auth, (data) => {
      if (data) {
        setContext(auth);
        setIsLoading(false);
      } else {
        setIsLoading(true);
      }
    });
  }, [router.query?.message]);
    return (
      <div className="username-main-container">
        {!isLoading ? (
          <div className="username-container">
            <div className="user-img-container">
              <img
                src={context.currentUser?.photoURL}
                alt={context.currentUser?.displayName}
                className="user-img"
              />
            </div>
            <div className="information-container">
              <h1>{context?.currentUser?.displayName}</h1>
              <Link href={`/${router.query?.username}/public`}>
                <button className="btn">Send Annonymous Messages</button>
              </Link>
            </div>
          </div>
        ) : null}
      </div>
    );
}
```

I want to render a custom 404 page when the user accidentally goes to an invalid URL but instead, this code just loads the data of the currently signed-in user.

As you can see this is a static page so I want the solution for static pages. I know you can set `notFound: true` in SSR or set the `fallback: false` in ISR pages but I am looking for a solution for completely static pages.

Comment: _"when the user accidentally goes to an invalid URL"_ - what makes a URL invalid in this case?

Answer (score -1):

```js
// pages/404.js
export default function Custom404() {
  return <h1>404 - Page Not Found</h1>
}
```

This is for custom error
This is not necessary but if you want custom error do this
nextjs will automatically do this for you if someone go to unknown page this error will popup you can try that on development.

[Reference](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-error-page)

> You can use getStaticProps inside this page if you need to fetch data
> at build time.

Comment: I am sorry I am a beginner in Next js but isn't the user of `getStaticProps` require the use of `getStaticPaths` as well. And that would be ISR instead of Client-Side Rendering.

Comment: @IbraheemHaseeb If you are going to use Slug or dynamically routes you need getStaticPaths but if it's just a static pages you don't need to use getStaticPaths.